# out of memory for immutable type in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I check id(A) each time in the loop below, I see its different (could be due to immutability). If yes, is there a chance of running out of memory in case long running loops which contains an assignment? Or is it a better idea to 
 del A before any new assignment?

```
A = 10
for count in range(1,<a very high number>):
    A = count
```

Answer (score 1):

On python2.7 `range` returns a list. I would be more worried about that list causing you memory issues.

You only ever need to `del` a variable if you have a long running function and you have a *very* large object that you want to free sooner rather than later. You'll never have an integer that will be anywhere near that large. For instance, a mere ten bytes is enough to store an integer that is larger than the number of atoms in the observable universe.

If you assign to a variable, then if the previous object only had one reference then it will automatically be freed. eg.

```
import weakref # module that doesn't keep objects in memory if it has the only reference

class A(object):
    pass

a = A()
r = weakref.ref(a)
print(a is r())
a = 1
print(r() is None)
```

Comment: Agree. I know integer takes very less space. I want to ensure that it really creates a new copy for each assignment. And there is a probability of out of memory at least in theory. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It will create a new integer, yes. But the previous integer will be freed very quickly, if not immediately (depending on your version of python).

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7 the `range()` function produce a list of `int` and (of course) stores it all in memory, if you have a very big list you could theoretically run out of memory (even though it should be *very* big). You should use `xrange()` instead which produce an iterator, so you will have just one `int` at a time in memory.

In python 3 all iterables are looped over using iterators by default, so the `range()` function behaves exactly like `xrange()` in python 2.7

Comment: A = 10
print id(A)

A = 20
print id(A)

A += 20

print id(A) its not the question of range. Any assignment to an integer or float value as above, produce a new id. I used a loop with range to keep it shorter.

Comment: @Anand I don't get it, an int (or float, or any other immutable) occupy always the same amount of memory (how much depends on the architecture), you won't run out of memory because you are incrementing an int, you may run out of memory because you hold a huge list of int in memory,

Comment: @Anand if your concern is about changing ids, you shouldn't worry, the garbage collector will take care of the unused objects (object which are not pointed by any variable anymore).

Comment: @Obrix: I wanted to check who takes care of automatic garbage collection. As you mentioned, I assume, the python garbage collector clears it. So any immutable types, old copies automatically get cleared. Thanks for helping out.